# How to add in a model collection an associated row of related a model in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I don't know if my title is right so feel free to edit this post and remove this first paragraph of my post.

I am trying to create a simple API in Laravel and I'm having a problem when i get a paginated shoutouts records to include the users who create it. I have 1 is to 1 relationship between User and Shoutout model and in the tables the shoutouts have the foreign key of user_id since the user is who created the shoutout and not the shoutout created the user.

So I tried to get a collection of shoutouts and include the user associated with it with this method:

```
$shoutouts = Shoutout::with('user')->paginate(15);
```

but I Having this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.shoutout_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`shoutout_id` in (1))
```

and it looks like the query trying to find shoutout_id to users table and since the foreign key is in the shoutouts table it gets an error in query. If I use this method:

```
$user = User::with('shoutout')->paginate(15);
```

there is no problem in querying, but the problem is its now a collection of users not a collection of shoutouts and the shoutout is nested in it, not the user is nested in shoutout collection. Is there a method(function) to use to get what i wanted to happen or a way to do that if if there is no method. I cant find any related question or maybe just my keyword for searching is wrong, feel free to suggest a link here if there is a related question to this question.

edited:
I think i will use query builder instead, but if there is method to achieve this in Eloquent I will upvote for that

Comment: Can you post your model code? You mention a 1 to 1 relationship between user and shoutout - I expect they should be 1 (user) to many (shoutout).

Comment: @BrynJ its my own preference that is 1 is to 1 relationship, coz i dont want too many data, and my only purpose is to practice creating API and also consuming it data while practising create mobile app using cordova, and the reason i choose 1 is to 1 is my hosting only have 1GB capacity so i dont need too much data btw this is the content of relationship
 return $this->hasOne('App\Shoutout');
return $this->hasOne('App\User');

Comment: @BrynJ i dont have problem in relationship, but in querying the data, and i solve it using query builder easily

Comment: The issue is your relationship definition. One side of the 1 to 1 relationship (the side with your foreign key) must be set as belongsTo https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @BrynJ you are right. i thought it should the same, i look at documentation and see the inverse or relationship and saw it, thanks man